# Getting different checksum values

Tags: numbers, md5, checksum

I have uploaded a PDF document to database as a BLOB with it's checksum number. When I am getting that BLOB back to PDF file and trying to calculate the checksum number then its giving a different checksum number then the original one. I would like to maintain the document integrity by using checksum number but due to this issue I am not able to maintain that.
Here for all the above mentioned operation I am doing in java.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Kuldeep

Comment: I do not think it is possible to help you with such small amount of info.

Comment: I am using below code to retrieve BLOB from DB

Comment: @Artur
I am using below code to retrieve BLOB from DB
 BLOB blob = (BLOB)rs.getObject(i);
 File pdfFile =
 new File(strPDFTmpDwnldDir + rs.getString(DBColumnName.FILENAME.getColumnName()));
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
 fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
 InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
 int b = 0;
 while (is.read(buffer) >b) {
 fos.write(buffer);
 }
 fos.close();
Is it possible to get the exact file from DB so that I can maintain the same checksum number.